# Handling change event for a dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, handler

I am trying to handle a change event for a dropdrown which looks like this:

```
 <div>
    <select id="serviceLine">
      <option selected="selected">--Select Option--</option>
      <option>Integration</option>
      <option>BPM</option>
      <option>GWT</option>
      <option>Other</option>
    </select>
 </div>
```

Now,I want to add a textarea when the user selects option "Others".
The jQuery looks like this:

```
function otherHandler(){
       $(this).siblings("textarea").remove();
       if($(this).val()=="Other"){

              var textbox="<textarea rows='3'></textarea>";
              $(this).parent().append(textbox);
       }

}

$("#serviceLine").on("change",function(){otherHandler()});
```

This doesn't work, because in `otherHandler() $(this)` contains the reference of the entire window and not just the dropbox.

However if I change my jQuery to this, it works fine:-

```
function otherHandler(that){
       $(that).siblings("textarea").remove();
       if($(that).val()=="Other"){

              var textbox="<textarea id='slOther'rows='3'></textarea>";
              $(that).parent().append(textbox);
       }

}


$("#serviceLine").on("change",function(){otherHandler(this)});
```

My question is why didn't it work in the first case, why do we have to pass the reference explicitly? Am I missing something major here?

Comment: If you have `otherHandler` wrapped in an anonymous function for some reason, like there's other code before or after it, then you can obtain the proper `this` value in `otherHandler()` by using `.call()` or `.apply()` to invoke the function. `otherHandler.call(this)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raed [this keyword](https://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/)

```
$("#serviceLine").on("change",function(){
    //this --> is local to the function block here you cannot use it outside
});
```

---

```
$("#serviceLine").on("change",function(){otherHandler(this)});
                                                      //^
```

Here you pass the reference of this to the function so it works

---

Better use

```
$("#serviceLine").on("change", otherHandler);
                                //^ function name
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first case it didn't worked as `this` is for defined for the event handler.

```
$("#serviceLine").on("change",function(){
    // this is accessible here in event handler not in the otherHandler function call
     otherHandler();
});
```

You should have directly passed the reference of function

```
$("#serviceLine").on("change", otherHandler);
```

If you wish you can use `.apply(this)`

```
function otherHandler(){
       $(this).siblings("textarea").remove();
       if($(this).val()=="Other"){

              var textbox="<textarea rows='3'></textarea>";
              $(this).parent().append(textbox);
       }

}

$("#serviceLine").on("change",function(){
   otherHandler.apply(this);
});
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. Not sure why it's getting downvoted. +1